# How to upload all logs in directory recursively with Fluent Bit?

Tags: logging, fluent-bit

Using Fluent Bit to upload directory:

```
[INPUT]
    Name      tail
    Path      /var/log/*
```

Only files directly under /var/log/ are handled, but files in sub-directory are not handled.

I've also tried using the `**` syntax, but Fluent Bit doesn't support this.

Is there a way to upload entire directory, with it's sub-directories with Fluent Bit?