# Fluent-bit doesn't collect logs recursively

Tags: fluent-bit

I am trying to create a forwarder base on fluent-bit instance and I encountered following issue related to collecting log files recursively. I found similar question but without response:
[How to upload all logs in directory recursively with Fluent Bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320584/how-to-upload-all-logs-in-directory-recursively-with-fluent-bit)
Related task you can find on GitHub:
https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/2120

Currently I am not able to collect logs from sub directories from provided location.
My INPUT configuration below:

```
[INPUT]
Name    tail
Path    /data/AirflowLogs/logs/**/*.log
Tag     airflow
```

It looks like fluent-bit does not support `**/*` matching. I know that fluentd handle it.
Any idea? How to collect logs recursively? Or maybe someone had a similar issue and know some workarounds? Regards!